# App Launcher Icons doesn't show after System update to 21.10 which upgraded Gnome to 40

Tags: gnome, updates, icons, desktop-icons, 21.10

App Launcher Icons doesn't show after System update to 21.10 which upgraded Gnome to 40
but please note that when i search for applications it lists normally... and i tried switching between Icon Themes and the following commands

```
sudo update-desktop-database
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache 
xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate 
gnome-shell --replace
```

but nothing worked

**Windowing System**: Wayland
**Gnome Version**: 40.4.0
**OS Name**: Ubuntu 21.10

EDIT:

- click the "all applications" icon on the dock and they are still less expected and less than the icons configured on `/usr/share/applications` and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`...
- but the search prompt works and it lists searched applications normally...

Comment: Clarify: do you mean that no icons appear when you click for example the "all applications" icon on the dock? However, the search prompt is there, and that will display icons when you start searching? Or do you mean you cannot open the Application overview? Please edit your post and make the desciption more specific so other users can reproduce the steps you take and exactly identify the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @vanadium EDITED...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this upgrade, you may benefit from resetting the layout of the application overview to the default. You can do so with the following command.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout
```

After this, the Application overview will populate with the default icons in the default order.

Note that as of Gnome 40 icons on the Dash do not anymore appear on the pages, i.e. each application icon exists only once, either on the pages, on the dash (which also functions as the dock in Ubuntu), or in a group (e.g. Utilities). You can drag the icons around to customize the view.

Comment: > `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout`
unfortunately, this didn't affect anything...

> `Note that as of Gnome 40 icons on the Dash do not anymore appear on the pages, i.e. each application icon exists only once, either on the pages, on the dash (which also functions as the dock in Ubuntu), or in a group (e.g. Utilities). You can drag the icons around to customize the view.`

you're right.....